# Website scrolling on a smartphone

Tags: html, css

I am a complete novice when it comes to website design, but have the task of designing a website for an academic conference. I wanted to design a functional site to which I understood the code behind it. I have managed to do so, but am now having problems with viewing it on a smartphone. When I have checked the website on online simulators such as [brick and mobile](http://www.brickandmobile.com/mobile-emulator/) is seems to work fine. However, when colleagues of mine with smartphones try looking at it, the main content area will not scroll. Does anyone know of a way to resolve this. The url to the website is:

[Conference Website](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~dward/)

Edit: The problem appears to be on android phones. If you zoom in a tiny bit you can then scroll alright, and if you move to a portrait view rather than a landscape view it is fine, but it will not scroll on a landscape view on an android.

Comment: The content of the page scrolls on my iPhone. However the site isn't optimal for viewing on a mobile device. I would consider detecting device and redirecting to a mobile version or alternatively employing responsive web design techniques. Although all this will take time and effort!

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone as well.  It looks like you're using frames, which might be causing interface issues on other devices?  The use of frames in general is frowned upon, you'll want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am aware that the viewing is by no means optimal. However, as long as it is viewable I am happy (most people will be viewing it on a pc or mac. The problem appears to be on an android phone as described in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want tot try adding viewport meta to your header, ensuring every device sees your site at the optimal width (this eliminates the user having to zoom in on most mobile devices).

You can find some good information for this in the following article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/

There are some zooming issues with the website on a Samsung Galaxy S2. This has mostly to do with your menu, which is set to 21%.

Furthermore you're setting height on a lot of elements to 100%. You might want to look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have now opted for a slightly different style for the mobile version of the website to make things simpler.